# CodeIgniter - csrf защита - form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой: При разработке сайта на локальном ПК, на dewner сделал функцию защиты от CSRF - это защита от POST данных с других сайтов. Установил в `config.php` поле

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```

тем самым активировал защиту. Теперь с помощью `form helper` функцией `form_open` я открываю все формы, а эта функция как раз в форму вставляет невидимый инпут с хешом для безопасности. - Все работает.

Перенес сайт на хостинг, в конфиге поменял адрес `base_url` на текущий сайт. Но почему-то теперь защита не работает и выдает ошибку при отправке post данных. Почему это может происходить? Я ничего не менял, только в конфиге `base_url`... Или же еще нужно что-то поменять? Как решить проблему? Заранее спасибо.

Ошибка:

> The action you have requested is not allowed.

Comment: Уточните, какая ошибка выводится? Мы тут просто под вечер теряем экстрасенсорные способности :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Связано это именно с

```
 $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

Если выставить в FALSE то ошибка пропадет.

Можно попробовать в контроллере прописать, хотя не уверен что поможет.

```
$this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE);
```

Поле в форме такое присутствует?

```
 <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->csrf_token_name?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->csrf_hash?>" />
```

Быть может нужно прописать так

```
 $this->input->_enable_csrf = TRUE;
```

На официальном англоязычном форуме написано так

```
 if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/callbacker') === FALSE) // ну callbacker скорее всего строка с которой приходит инфа.
    {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо. Пробовал все по порядку. Прописываю в контроллере, в конструкторе: $this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE); . Проверяю исходный код страницы, строка инпута с сессией есть. Отправил пост - не выдал ошибки. Попробовал с другого сайта передать пост данные - он их почему то передал, ошибки не было. Не сработало. Поле невидимого инпута добавляется автоматически, если указывать form_open(); - у меня так.  $this->input->_enable_csrf = TRUE; - точно не понял смысл, но прописал в конструкторе - не помогло. И последний вариант, добавил в конфиг - происходит тоже что и пре включенном.

Comment: >Попробовал с другого сайта передать пост данные - он их почему то передал,

я бы тоже их передал через CURL :)

смысл в запрете отправки данных с другого сайта? уж лучше сделать проверку на передаваемые.

Я чесно ХЗ как работает эта "защита"

Comment: Логично подумать, если через denwer функция срабатывала, а на хосте нет, думаю, что дело в конфигурациях хоста. включил там и там phpinfo() - посмотрел заметил, что Register_globals был разный, сделал одинаковым не помогло. Значит в чем-то другом. Как думаете? =)

Comment: а как ты с другого сайта отправляешь данные?

ведь скрытое поле генериться автоматом для каждого появления формы?

Comment: На другом сайте создал форму и указал на основной сайт с передачей пост данных.

Скрытое поле генерится автоматом, но не при каждом появление формы. Там по времени жизни сессии.

Comment: так в том то и дело что форма то отправится, но твой сайт эту форму просто не должен обработать, а принять данные должен :)

Comment: Эта защита нужна, чтобы на любом другом сайте нельзя было бы сделать форму, которая ведет на основной сайт и выполняет действия от имени пользователя. Например: На любом другом сайте стоит форма и кнопка "Нажми", человек нажал - форма отправилась, и например удалил аккаунт, передала деньги злоумышленнику и т.д. А эта защита работает с помощью сессий и делает запрос уникальным при отправке формы.

Comment: сайт должен понять, что данные отправляются с другого сайта и выдать ошибку, а если запросы в внутри сайта, они имеют сессии, то они уже обрабатываются.

Comment: Должно генериться такого вида: <input type="hidden" name="ci_csrf_token" value="135cbb7545ae5e0692b36175953a6a14" />

Comment: ты хочешь сказать что ты отправляешь форму с другого сайта и "по мгновению волшебной палочки" в этой форме появляется скрытая хеш переменная с твоего сайта? не поверю никогда. если только это не iframe с твоего сайта.

я же пишу "код формы" в студию.

Comment: Нет, не понял меня. Вообщем, не в то русло поехали. Codeigniter уже все сделал, нужно лишь, чтобы работало. Так вот, при включение в конфиге, то отправка формы выдает ошибки, хотя там присутствует скрытая сессия строка. Я не много потестил и заметил, что он должен добавлять эту сессию в куки и сверять, но он туда не добавляет, я в куки не увидел. Как решить проблему можно эту?

Comment: завтра стукни в скайп, пообщаемся.

Answer (score 1):

Там были изменения в новой версии, читайте changelog!
Вот рабочий пример для версии 2.1.2:

Конфиг:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_hash';
```

Отображение:

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="<?=$this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>">
```